# How to Display Selected row from Datagrid view into text boxes using C#

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm storing all the user registration on `user_reg` database table and importing them to data grid view and I use a separate windows form to input the data. When the data is imported from database to data grid view my name column is shown as one(first name, middle name and last name are joined.) My problem is that, when I try to import the data from data grid view to my windows form the **Name** coloumn is not showing properly on the Windows Form(it displays as one, but my from has 3 separate text boxes.) I have done this =>

```
private void Update_Users_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long totalRow = 0;


        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `user_reg`.`user_id`, `user_reg`.`first_name`, `user_reg`.`middle_name`, `user_reg`.`last_name`, `user_reg`.`address`, `user_reg`.`sex`, `user_reg`.`nic_number`, `user_reg`.`contact_number`, `user_reg`.`email_address`, `user_reg`.`user_type` FROM `sarasavi_library`.`user_reg` WHERE `user_id`='" + borrower_id + "';", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds, "user_reg");

        totalRow = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows.Count - 1;

        txt_uid.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
        txt_fname.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        txt_mname.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        txt_lname.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
        txt_address.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
        com_sex.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
        txt_nic.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();
        txt_contact.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();
        txt_email.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(8).ToString();
        com_memtype.Text = ds.Tables["user_reg"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(9).ToString();

    }
```

But my problem is that it doesn't run but give me the error

> The name `borrower_id` does not exist in the current context.

borrower_id is the name from the data grid view, I can't figure out a way to include it. Any ideas on how to include this?? For better understanding I will attach an image [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKyLg.jpg)

Comment: try  int _id =     (int)dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[borrower_id.Index].Value; and use the _id instead. although this depends on which row of the datagrid you want to read the id from, and also note that i consider your borrower_id is actually a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The name borrower_id does not exist in the current context.

This exception indicates that the compiler does not know what "**borrower_id**" is. That is because (based on the code snippet) you never declared it anywhere before using it. The only instance I see is when you used it to construct your query.

Unless "**borrower_id**" is a property (which is why you omitted its declaration from your snippet), you need to declare it before using it in order for the compiler to know what it is.

Comment: That's my problem edmundv, don't know how to declare the data gridview to use it on this form. Any ideas?

Comment: @DilumJayawardhana How is your Update_Users_Load called? Does it come from the Borrowers form; like a double-click, or button click, etc.? If that's the case then you can simply pass the ID(borrower_id) on the SelectedItem from that window to the calling method in order to get the id for your SQL query. If not, explain how it is called and I might be able to assist with the better solution.

Comment: when a row is selected from data grid view(Borrowers form), I use a button click event to load the Update_users form. Can you please provide an example

Comment: I normally use DataGrid in WPF, but you can try something like this: GridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text, (Since your id is in the second cell). I would first validate the content of the cell, then use it in the query. So if all this is in your code behind, you can simple validate the GridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1] and pass it in place of borrower_id, or you can descare borrower_id as a string and assign the value of GridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1] to if and not change the code that you currently have; just add the declaration and assignment.

Comment: I used a different method, anyway appreciate your help. Thanks